# Python Error when inputing numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program in Python to tell me one thing if the inputed number is between 1 and 100.  This is the code I have so far:

```
number = int (raw_input ("give me a number."))

if number < 100 and number > 1:
    print ("Great! The number " + number + " is in fact between 1 and 100. I am happy " + number + " times")

if number < 1 or number < 100:
    print ("Not so great! The number " + number + " is not between 1 and 100.")
```

I can run the first bit, but once I input a number that is between 1 and 100, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Downloads/number (1).py", line 3, in <module>
    print "Great! " + number + " is in fact between 1 and 100"
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: also you could improve your if statement by `if 1 <= number <= 100:` and `else:`  as it is right now the `number` `100` and `1` are not caught

Comment: doesn't `number > 1 or number < 100` always evaluate to True? Name a number that is both less than one and greater than a hundred ;-)

Comment: @Kevin that's true for integers, but not for floating points. Try `NaN`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't combine `int` and `str` directly. Either convert to string or use string formatting:

Preferred:

```
print ("Not so great! The number {} is not between 1 and 100.".format(number))
```

At one point deprecated, now sticking around, but considered "old":

```
print ("Not so great! The number %i is not between 1 and 100." % number)
```

Most explicit, slowest, least preferred, and bad style (thanks @Stefano Sanfilippo!):

```
print ("Not so great! The number " + str(number) + " is not between 1 and 100.")
```

If you had `"5" + 5`, what would you want? Do you want `10`, or do you want `"55"`? Because of the ambiguity, it's safer to raise an error and force you to be explicit with your intention

Comment: i think theres also %i

Comment: You should say that the third form is bad coding style in Python.

Comment: convert int to str is not an issue, convert unicode strings to str BTW drove me nuts so many times!! xDD

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert 'number' into a string. You can do this by wrapping it up with the 'str' function.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
print ("Great! The number "+str(number)+" is in fact between 1 and 100. I am happy " +str(number)+" times")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add strings and integers together directly.  Doing so will throw a `TypeError`:

```
>>> 'a' + 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
>>>
```

Instead, you can use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to insert the integers into the string:

```
print("Not so great! The number {0} is not between 1 and 100.".format(number))
```

---

Also, the logic of your comparisons is wrong.  For example, the condition of this if-statement:

```
if number > 1 or number < 100:
```

will always evaluate to `True` because `number` will *always* be greater than `1` or less than `100`.

---

With these problems addressed, your code should look like this:

```
number = int(raw_input("give me a number."))

# You can chain comparisons
if 1 < number < 100:
    print("Great! The number {0} is in fact between 1 and 100. I am happy {0} times".format(number))
# You should use else here
else:
    print("Not so great! The number {0} is not between 1 and 100.".format(number))
```